# Nancy Localization - Separate Resource Library

Tags: localization, nancy

I have a website hosted by Nancy, I need the Razor web pages to use resource strings that will be implemented in resource files that reside in a separate library.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The main problem for this is, that you can only acess string resources from the assembly where the resouces is defined. To solve this, just add code that retrieves the text into the assembly where you want to place the text resource and call it from where you need the texts